# Datascroller issue - When dataTable and dataScroller is nested inside loop

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl, richfaces, jsf-2.2

***DataScroller pagination issue - The requested page #2 isn't found in the model containing 1 pages. Paging is reset to page #1***

I have used `a4j:repeat` to iterate `rich:dataTable` and `rich:datascroller`. The problem with `rich:datascroller` is that pagination is not working properly.

I have also tried **JSTL** `c:foreach` also. But, still I am getting the following error in console.

> (UIDatascroller.java:471) - Datascroller indexId:j_id129:j_id139: The requested page #2 isn't found in the model containing 1 pages. Paging is reset to page #1

In the PageBean.java

```
private List parentList;
public List getParentList() {
    return parentList;
}
public void setParentList(List parentList) {
    this.parentList = parentList;
}
public String openPage(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        List<BeanDto> dtoList = ...;
        if(dtoList!=null){
            if(parentList==null){
                parentList = new ArrayList<List<BeanDto>>();
            }
            parentList.add(dtoList);
        }
    }
    return "page"
}
```

In the page.xhtml

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{pageBean.parentList}" var="item">
    <rich:dataTable id="table" rows="2" var="childDto" value="#{item}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <rich:columnGroup>
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Age" />
                </rich:column>
            </rich:columnGroup>
        </f:facet>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{childDto.name}"/>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{childDto.age}"/>
            </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>

    <rich:datascroller for="table" maxPages="10">
    </rich:datascroller>
</a4j:repeat>
```

Tables were displayed in the screen, but pagination is not working.

I have also tried to give index to the `<rich:dataTable>`'s `id`; That is also not woeking properly. Could you help me on this.

Comment: An issue **cannot** be at the same time a jsf 1.2 AND jsf 2/2.2 problem.

Comment: @Kukeltje: We are experiencing only in jsf 2, still I have tagged jsf 1.2 to make it reach for JSF gurus and help us to close this issue as fast as they could.